# How to get attribute group name by id

Tags: magento2, eav, attribute-group

How to get attribute group name by attribute group id

```
<?php 
$attribute_group_id = 2; /// this is group id 

echo likeGetnameforthis($attribute_group_id);

?>
```

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-attribute-group-details-by-id-magento-2/ you can try this way for get group name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeGroupRepositoryInterface::get` to get the desired group by the id. Then you can call `\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeGroupInterface::getAttributeGroupName`

An example class could be:

```
<?php

class Example {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeGroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $groupRepository;

    /**
     * Example constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeGroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeGroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository)
    {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param $groupId
     *
     * @return string|null
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAttributeGroupNameById($groupId)
    {
        return $this->groupRepository->get($groupId)->getAttributeGroupName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i got This Error
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes

Comment: Where and how did you implement it?